# Do not combine generators in Catch2 test case

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch2

I would like to use to more than one generator in a `Catch2` test case. My problem is, that when there are more than two generators, they are "combined". So if I write something like this:

```
TEST_CASE("Test legal moves on empty 2x1 board") {
    Board board(2, 1);

    auto startPos = GENERATE(Position(0, 0), Position(1, 0));
    auto expectedMoves = GENERATE(Position(1, 0), Position(0, 0));
    auto legalMoves = board.getLegalMoves(startPos);
    REQUIRE(legalMoves[0] == expectedMoves);
}
```

This will result in four test cases:
(`startPos[0] vs expectedMoves[0]`, `startPos[0] vs expectedMoves[1]`, `startPos[1] vs expectedMoves[0]`, `startPos[1] vs startPos[1]`).

I however want only two: (`startPos[0] vs expectedMoves[0]`, `startPos[1] vs startPos[1]`).

**Is there a way to do it in an elegant and readable way?** I would like to avoid things like this:

```
TEST_CASE("Test legal moves on empty 2x1 board") {
    Board board(2, 1);

    auto dump = GENERATE(vector<Position>{ Position(0, 0), Position(1, 0) },    
                         vector<Position>{ Position(1, 0), Position(0, 0) }); 
    auto expectedMoves = dump[1];       
    auto legalMoves = board.getLegalMoves(dump[0]);       
    REQUIRE(legalMoves[0] == expectedMoves);
}
```

As maintenance of such monstrosity is cumbersome.

EDIT: I do not really like this solution:
https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/ce42deb72fab2be85a862f559984580c24cb76c4/projects/SelfTest/UsageTests/Generators.tests.cpp#L199

Comment: Could you explain what is dump about your dump solution, beside using vector instead of some meaningful named struct with meaningful named members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using multiple generators you should wrap your input/output test data in some structure that will define both `startPos` and `expectedMove`. Then you can use single generator to produce data sets. Your data will be named, so you don't have to reference to it by index. Your `TEST_CASE` could look like this:

```
struct TestData
{
    Position startPos;
    Position expectedMove;
};

TEST_CASE("Test legal moves on empty 2x1 board")
{
    Board board {2, 1};
    auto testData = GENERATE(TestData {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, TestData {{1, 0}, {0, 0}});
    auto lagalMoves = board.getLegalMoves(testData.startPos);
    REQUIRE(lagalMoves[0] == testData.expectedMove);
}
```